# How can one sign a message to prove ownership of a BIP47 reusable payment code?

Tags: message-signing, bip47, reusable-payment-code

Is there a way to sign a message and prove that an entity owns a BIP47 reusable payment code? How can this be done via js if available?

Answer (score 1):

yes, sign with the bip47 notification private key